# How I can check if gmail account really exist with ionic2 and firebase?

Tags: firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication

I am currently working with ionic2 and firebase technology. How can I verify if the gmail account with which the user is signing in to my app really exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can send your users a verification email and have them verify their email address.

```js
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

user.sendEmailVerification().then(function() {
    // Email sent.
}, function(error) {
    // An error happened.
});
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#send_a_user_a_verification_email

Comment: As an addition, if the email is accepted, with your unique reference, then you can add them to your Firebase data.